# Error in Firefox when closing the modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, file-upload, firebug

I have a modal window which has an accordion in it and one of the accordions has a file upload . I click on the browse, window open up to select a file, I close the window without selecting the file. Now, I try to close the modal window by clicking on the close button it throws

> NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO: Security Manager vetoed action arg
>   0 [nsIDOMHTMLDivElement.contains]

in the javascript console. Has anybody had this problem and how to fix this ? 
I am using jquery-ui 1.8.18 and jquery 1.7.1 min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this article here:  https://github.com/mihaild/jquery-html5-upload/issues/2

Someone had this issue, it seem they fixed it.

It is fixed in [jQuery-UI 1.8.21](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8288)

Comment: Is there any workaround you know of ? I have seen that and I am not sure if I can update my jquery which looks stable for me.

Comment: It seem the problem occurs only in jQuery-UI 1.8.18. This problem didnt occur to previous version. It is a micro update between 1.8.18 to 1.8.21. I would suggest updating your jQuery-UI code, I don't see major changes that might break your current code that work with 1.8.18. But I didn't read the changelog, so don't hold my word on it.

Comment: I tried to recreate the situation using a simple jsp page with latest jquery and jquery UI from here https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery. The problem still persists in my firefox 14.0.1

Comment: Seems like its a bug in firefox 14, I had updated to 15 and I no longer face that issue

Comment: Bug with FF is highly possible. I believe what the code tried to do with FF is doing something that is (or used to be from FF15) illegal from FF security perspective. I've contributed to FF before, and it is good to note they often change their security policies as the web and HTML5 evolved.