# NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO Error In FF 30.0 Using Selenium IDE 2.5.0 To Populate Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-ide

When running a selenium IDE script to autofill a form, I receive the following:

```
[error] There was an unexpected Alert! [Javascript Error :MY-SUPER-TOP-SECRET-URL line 37 Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO: ]
```

When I checked line 37, it is a tiny block of code setting a global bool, wrapped in a jQuery click() anon function.

```
  parent.jQuery(parent.document).click(function () {
     parent.sharedVars.enableGenderKey = false;
  });
```

I am running jQuery 1.8.3.  Any tips? Interestingly, the form DOES fill successfully once, but on attempt 2 and above, it errors.

Comment: Does this helps? Should be fixed in jquery-UI 1.8.21 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202566/error-in-firefox-when-closing-the-modal-window

Comment: thank you, but it does not.  We upgraded our version to 1.11.x without change in behavior.

Answer (score 2):

We traced it down, we believe to bad SSL certs.  We couldn't confirm it absolutely, but once the certs got settled, the issue seemed to vanish

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I got this error today (jQuery 2.2.3 and Firefox 46.0.1). I had (A) a form post that caused (B) an iframe to load with jQuery code that (C) created elements in the parent of the iframe. Some of these had an anonymous function to handle click events. When clicked, this function caused (D) a form submit, again to the iframe.

The function in (D) worked once, then on the second (and every subsequent) click the above mentioned veto-error occurred. This is a similar setting to what the OP describes: an anonymous jQuery function doing something with a form more than once.

With that theory, I refactored my whole solution to avoid this and got rid of the error.

Here's the workaround that did it in my case: I have a javascript function in the page (outside the iframe) to handle what I want to do.

```
function myclick(e)
{
  if (!$(e.target.hasClass('wantclick'))) return;
  actualstuff();
}
```

I bind `onclick='myclick(event);'` to the div where the jQuery code from the iframe places new stuff into. Inside the iframe, I have jQuery do `.addClass('wantclick')`.

Comment: do you also have invalid SSL certs?

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same error on my firefox 57, Linux mint 14.04
I was working on some project with jquery. At first the error didn't pop until I did a POST request and used [`complete()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) callback method to process the jqXHR object (see deprecation notice), that's how it appeared in the console. 
But the symptoms were always here: 
My browser was kind of hanging, so I had to press F5 each time. I commented some `alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR))` and the error disappeared, not the symptoms.

I checked with Chrome and Chromium, no such error.
I could not say what was the reason, but I had it resolved simply by restarting my browser but possibly a cache issue with Firefox

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

We had this **in a frameset environment where we were holding a reference to some previously loaded and now invalid and thrown away frame content (via some jQuery object)** that had been refreshed already and thus was non-existing anymore.

**Refreshing the jQuery frame object before accessing it fixed it.**